# ToObservable is not firing in some cases

Tags: system.reactive

RX is synchronous by default so we can confirm it

```cs
            int j = 0;
            Observable.Range(1, 2)
                .SelectMany(i => {
                    return new[]{1}.ToObservable()
                            .Select(i1 => {
                                new[]{1}.ToObservable().Subscribe(i2 => j = 1);
                                return 0;
                            })
                        ;
                })
                .Subscribe();
            j.ShouldBe(1);
```

however in my code base I have a similar query that does not fire unless i use the Immediate scheduler.

```cs
 public static IObservable<GitHubIssue> Save(this IObservable<IReadOnlyList<Issue>> source,  IGitHubRepository repository){
            var objectSpace = repository.ObjectSpace;
                return source.SelectMany(list => list.ToObservable().Select(issue => {
                    var gitHubIssue = objectSpace.CreateObject<GitHubIssue>();
                    gitHubIssue.Id = issue.Id;
                    issue.Labels.ToObservable(Scheduler.Immediate).Select(label => {
                        var gitHubLabel =objectSpace.GetObjectsQuery<GitHubLabel>(true).FirstOrDefault(_ => label.Name == _.Name) ??
                                         objectSpace.NewGitHubLabel(label);
                        gitHubIssue.Labels.Add(gitHubLabel);
                        return gitHubLabel;
                    }).Subscribe();
                    //previous selector is not executed
```

i fail to see the relation and why this happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"RX is synchronous by default" - No, it is not. Each operator has its own default.

Take `Observable.Range` for example. Here's the implementation for when you don't provide a `Scheduler`:

```
public virtual IObservable<int> Range(int start, int count)
{
    return Range_(start, count, SchedulerDefaults.Iteration);
}
```

Which in turn uses:

```
internal static IScheduler Iteration
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance;
    }
}
```

If I take `Observable.Timer` as an counterpoint, I have this code:

```
public virtual IObservable<long> Timer(TimeSpan dueTime)
{
    return Timer_(dueTime, SchedulerDefaults.TimeBasedOperations);
}
```

Which uses:

```
internal static IScheduler TimeBasedOperations
{
    get
    {
        return DefaultScheduler.Instance;
    }
}
```

The fact that you have to put in `.ToObservable(Scheduler.Immediate)` says you have an operator that doesn't use `Scheduler.Immediate` by default.

Now, ignoring all of this, what you should never ever do inside an observable pipeline is subscribe to another observable. Never ever. When you do this you are relying on side-effects and that's what's going wrong in your code.

You should always assume that any call to `Subscribe` runs sometime in the future, so even your assertion that `j.ShouldBe(1)` shouldn't ever be used after a `Subscribe`.

Your sample code should be more like this:

```
int j = 0;
Observable
    .Range(1, 2)
    .SelectMany(i =>
    {
        return
            new[] { 1 }
                .ToObservable()
                .Select(i1 =>
                {
                    return 1;
                })
            ;
    })
    .Subscribe(x => 
    {
        j = x;
        /* j only valid here */
    });

/* j NOT valid here */
```

---

Rational concrete example of a side-effect:

```
int j = 0;
Observable
    .Delay(Observable.Return(42), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    .Do(x => j = x)
    .Subscribe();
Console.WriteLine(j);
```

Ultimately `j` will be equal to `42`, but not when `Console.WriteLine(j)` is called. Never rely on state outside of the observable that's updated within the observable.

Comment: >When you do this you are relying on side-effects
care to put a rational concrete example for this meaning?

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris - I've provided an example - it's trivial, but it encapsulates what I think is going on with your code.